# Change root node (response) wcf service

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf, service, response

I created a simple wcf service with default example of vs2013.  I need to change a root of response GetDataResponse in GetData

how can i do it?

```html
  
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header />
  <s:Body>
    <**GetDataResponse** xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <GetDataResult>You entered: 0</GetDataResult>
    </GetDataResponse>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Comment: GetDataResponse is generated from the name of GetData. You could rename GetData or add a different 'Name' property to the [OperationContract] attribute. Or craft your own WSDL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use Messagecontract in order to change(control) the SOAP request/response.For example:Create a new response class and decorate with MessageContract like below.

```
[MessageContract(IsWrapped=true, 
                     WrapperName="GetDataResponse", 
                     WrapperNamespace="http://MyCompany.com/Response")]
    public class GetDataInfo
    {
    }
```

Use the above class as a resposne object when WCF service is invoked.
Refer http://csharp-video-tutorials.blogspot.in/2013/11/part-10-message-contract-in-wcf_28.html for more detail info.

Comment: this example is exactly what I needed. thank you so much